# What is "failed to read block" and how can this be fixed?

Tags: bitcoin-core

When I try to open my BitCoin wallet, I get a "failed to read block" message and it will not open. What does this mean and how can this be rectified?

Comment: Client and version?

Comment: I downloaded 0.8.0 for Windows.

Comment: This helped me: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10295/bitcoin-qt-read-block-error