# Bitcoin-qt read block error

Tags: blockchain, linux

I am using linux mint 14 and was in the process of loading block files. I had a power failure and now it tells me failed to read Block. I would delete the blockchain and start over but IDK where to find it. I am not worried about loosing anything. Please help I am frustrated. I tried uninstalling but this did not work. Please be detailed in response I am a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the client on the command line with the flag `-reindex`.

Comment: OMG you are a life saver .. worked like a charm .. You are a God!! Thank you Thank you Thank you. I looked all over and could not get this answer.